# Why does the hash compare outputs true even without the salt parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, bcrypt

I use `bcrypt-nodejs` to generate a hash in my node.js app like that:

```
           var complete_string = "login" + "user@gmail.com";
           var salt = "89Uhfdsua8aHK";
           var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(complete_string, salt);
```

Then I try to check whether the hash from that string is correct using:

```
           bcrypt.compareSync(complete_string, hash)); // true
```

But why does the `compareSync` function outputs `true` even though I'm not giving it any `salt` parameter?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023361/how-does-node-bcrypt-js-compare-hashed-and-plaintext-passwords-without-the-salt ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does node.bcrypt.js compare hashed and plaintext passwords without the salt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023361/how-does-node-bcrypt-js-compare-hashed-and-plaintext-passwords-without-the-salt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you inspect `hash`, you'll notice that `hashSync()` prepends the salt to the output:

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const complete_string = "login" + "user@gmail.com";
const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(2);
console.log("salt: " + salt);
const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(complete_string, salt);
console.log("hash: " + hash);
console.log("compare: " + bcrypt.compareSync(complete_string, hash));
```

Outputs:

```
salt: $2a$10$k/a9i/zMGnzx5VKjmhXySO
hash: $2a$10$k/a9i/zMGnzx5VKjmhXySO.sx6fcIPsdbej1pVVcKLy9TbNK.2aLm
compare: true
```

It's common to store the salt with the hashed value for exactly this reason, so that it's possible to validate the hash later without having to pass the salt around as a separate value. The bcrypt library just happens to do this for you.